# Not the result you expect it should be

Tags: phrase-usage

When you had planned something, and it didn't occur the way you expect it, can you say:

> (storytelling)''Oh man, it was **not the result I expected it should be''**

Did the **bold letters**(phrase) usage correct?

Comment: I would just say "Oh man, it was not the result I expected."

Comment: Yeah, but can you go further by adding ''should be''

Comment: If you have to extend it, it sounds more fluent to say "**would** be", because it's a past-tense conditional ("I had expected the result would be X if _____").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stangdon points out

> It was not the result I expected it **would** be.

or you could also use

> It's not what I expected. *(applicable to anything)*

or referring to the *ending* in your examples

> It didn't end in the way I expected.
>   The ending was unexpected. *(more generalized to not just you)*

Answer (score 2):

No, it's a duplication. We can say

> The result I expected

Which is a transformation of

> I expected the result

and

> I expected it should be XXX

Your formulation joins the two.

However, I think in informal conversation we might use such a construct; when speaking we do tend to slip in extra phrases, while we think of what to say next, or we lose track of our sentence structure. In formal, written work we remove such extra verbiage.